# Can not convert from CursorLoader to Cursor<Loader> : SqlCipher cursor

Tags: cursor, android-cursorloader, sqlcipher

I am using SQLCipher to encrypt the android database.
I am getting typecast error (Can not convert from CursorLoader to Cursor) in the line for

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args){
..
..
return new CursorLoader(this, CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);
}
```

It will work if I am using the default Android database cursor.

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this. i have the exact same problem. thanks

Comment: I also have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap all your dataBase routines inside standard [`ContentProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) class. It export standard `android.database.Cursor` for all your needs and keep specific DB realisation inside.

Another way - use some DAO helpers (like http://greenrobot.org/greendao/features/) for wrapping around messy SQL's

Both methods can work with [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/)